# How to use an Enum?

Tags: java, enums

I'm programming for the first time a kind of big Program in Java, but this time I am using JavaFx.

I want to use an Enum in my code so I wrote an Enum class

```
public enum Directions {
    NORTH,
    SOUTH,
    WEST,
    EAST
}
```

and I wrote the Method:

```
public void changeDirection(Directions newDirections){// kommt noch
    switch (newDirections){
       case newDirection.NORTH: direction = 'n'; break;
       case newDirection.SOUTH: direction = 's'; break;
       case newDirection.WEST: direction = 'w'; break;
       case newDirection.EAST: direction = 'e'; break;
       default: break;
   }
}
```

Because I don't have a main class yet, and my Compiler does not work normal, I needed to ask if what I did was right.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Write a simple main method and try it out.  You will learn much more by trying things than just asking questions.

Comment: I do agree with you, but I have some problems with my Compiler and I need few more days to get a new PC to Install it in so this is why I do ask

Comment: Shouldn't all the cases be `case Directions.North` (and so on..) instead of  `newDirection.NORTH` ?

Comment: Maybe you could try an online compiler ? e.g. https://ideone.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What's the point of an enum if you still use switch? Just add a field of type char to the enum that holds n/s/w/e. And then it's something like newDirection.getChar(). Here's an example. I've also added a method `byChar` to get the enum element from a char.

```
public enum Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST;
    final char  c;

    private Direction() {
        this.c = Character.toLowerCase(this.name().charAt(0));
    }

    public char getChar() {
        return this.c;
    }

    public static Direction byChar(final char c) {
        for (final Direction dir : Direction.values())
            if (dir.c == c) return dir;
        throw new NoSuchElementException("No direction for " + c);
    }
}
```